# Camera "Jitter" When circling around object

Tags: animation, camera, parent

So I made a simple camera rig (camera clamped to nurbus circle and parented to an empty, dead center in middle) but I get this unwanted jitter, not sure what causes it, if someone knows solution, I would be grateful, thanks!

Problem shown in a Youtube video attached

[Youtube Link](https://youtu.be/LYLxEpKFBk8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like there is a conflict, two constraints fighting for control of the camera - the path and the empty.  To avoid this, have an empty follow the path, and parent the cam to the empty.  This will allow independent use of the cam, i.e. 'look at', rotation, etc.

[image]

I've used an invisible cube here to illustrate.

Comment: Thanks so much for your troubleshooting, yea I think I might used like two constraints and they were conflicting together or the circle resolution I was using was way too low.