# Sliding object along a curve

Tags: objects, bezier-curves

I have an icosphere and I want to move it following a curve. I want the centre of the icosphere to follow the curve.

I tried snapping, but seemingly this does not work with a curve. My intention is not animation but simply the design of the scene, so [movement along a path](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73025/move-object-along-path) is not what I want.

Comment: you can use a Follow Path constraint but just don't animate it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quickest hacky way of doing this is to convert the curve into a mesh by selecting curve and go to Object > Convert > Mesh.

[image]

Then turn on snapping with Snap To edge enabled and Snap With to Center.
Make sure Transform Pivot Point is set to Median Point.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce this :( Have converted my curve to Mesh, create a sphere, then __G__ the cursor snaps to the Mesh but the sphere locates just beside

Comment: Sorry. Also set Snap With to Center. I'll update my answer.

Comment: again, snap with option to center move the sphere even farther !

Comment: Is the Origin of the sphere in the center of the mesh?

Comment: It works first time with a new sphere, then anytime I want to move it along the "curve" it move away (yes Origin of Sphere at center of the geometry)

Comment: Can you upload a gif/video of what's happening? Or upload the blend to https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133139/discussion-between-the-world-is-not-flat-and-benus).

Answer (score 4):

As Moonboots wrote, just use Follow path constraint and don't tap on "animate path". You can define your position by sliding the offset:

[image]

Comment: I can only upvote this fantastic idea!!!!

Comment: Well actually it was just my own idea. Nobody else could ever ever EEEEVER have this gorgious idea which for sure  beats Einsteins E = mc2 (sorry cannot make little 2) and all these other stupids men ideas!!!! ‍♂️

Comment: please, Einstein was so wrong with his ridiculous E=MC2

Comment: plus I know only one MC: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=otCpCn0l4Wo

Comment: you don't know MCDonalds!? ‍♂️ i can't tou...believe this!!! 

Comment: Here store this artifact in your equipment, so you can use it later: ²

Comment: i put it in my safe - this is the most valuable i ever got here....sniff....