# How to make character run forward?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, armature

Here I need to make this character run forward in this corridor.

[image]

Following this path:

[image]

I've already done the run cycle but I can't find a way to make it move **while** running. I tried to slow down the fps rate and keyframing the character while it moves and other things but without succes.
There is maybe an add-on or an internal blender's function?

I'll attach the .blend file in the way it cuold be usefoul for helping me.
Thanks in advance!

.Blend file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/di4r9kp11h8rlf2/Concorso.blend?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any path for the character to run along so I'll include this link as to how to create a path and have avatars objects  move along them.  [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73025/move-object-along-path/73039?noredirect=1#comment127330_73039)

Instead of forcing the character to follow the path, place an empty there instead, have it follow the path, then parent your character to the empty, much as is done in this answer - [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71486/camera-jitter-when-circling-around-object/71518?noredirect=1#comment124472_71518)

This will give you more flexibility to steer the character's facing direction, rotation etc so it does as we do in real life, 'anticipate' the turns.

The running animation can run independently while the character is 'pulled' along the path by the Empty.

Comment: Ok, thank you a lot. I'ill update you if it works or not.

Comment: If you have't made a 'path' to follow before, it would pay to learn this using a simple cube in a fresh instance of Blender, get it working without the complications of an existing project getting in the way.  :)

Comment: Happy to help! :)

Comment: @Fly_7113,  If the above answer has solved your problem could you mark your question as Answered thanks.